# How to initialize my pointer to NULL

Tags: c, pointers

Learning C, I'm trying to implement a little program. I have two structs like this:

```
typedef struct QueueNode_ QueueNode;
typedef struct TQueue_ TQueue;

struct QueueNode_ {
    QueueNode* next;
    const Task task;
};

struct TQueue_ {
    QueueNode* first;
    QueueNode* last;
};
```

Next I defined a method to initialize my queue:

```
void initializeQueue(TQueue* queue){
    queue = malloc(sizeof(TQueue)); //check if malloc returns NULL!
    queue->first = NULL;
    printf("%d", queue->first == NULL);
    queue->last = NULL;
}
```

And the main:

```
int main() {
    puts("TQueue example:");

    TQueue q;
    initializeQueue(&q);
    printf("%d", q.first == NULL);
}
```

I though that the above would print `11` but it prints `10` meaning that my pointer `first` is not set to null. I'm pretty sure that I miss something basic...

Why the above prints 10 and how to initialize properly the pointer of first to NULL in my `initializeQueue` method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is the fault:

```
queue = malloc(sizeof(TQueue)); //check if malloc returns NULL!
```

You have already allocated memory for the structure in the `main` function, so you don't need to do it again.

In fact, what the line is doing is allocating memory, assigning it to the pointer (and remember that arguments are passed by value so it overwrites the *local copy*) and you change only that structure in the function, not the one passed in by the call.

Comment: Arrg. Stupid of me.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that in C, arguments are always passed by value, unless explicitly passed as a pointer, so generally speaking you should not assign the arguments directly: it is confusing.

```
void initializeQueue(TQueue* queue) {
    queue = malloc(sizeof(TQueue)); //check if malloc returns NULL!
```

See? Upon entering the function, `queue` points to the queue from `main`, but then you allocate a new struct and make `queue` point to it. So the queue from `main` is never initialized!

The solution, remove the `malloc`:

```
void initializeQueue(TQueue* queue){
    queue->first = NULL;
    printf("%d", queue->first == NULL);
    queue->last = NULL;
}
```

Or if you prefer to go fully dynamic, to not take the queue as an argument but return a newly allocated one:

```
TQueue *initializeQueue(){
    TQueue* queue = malloc(sizeof(TQueue)); //check if malloc returns NULL!
    queue->first = NULL;
    printf("%d", queue->first == NULL);
    queue->last = NULL;
    return queue;
}
```

And modify the `main` function accordingly.

Comment: Yes I had the first version working dynamically, but the teacher requires to use the signature `void initializeQueue(TQueue* queue)` and I forgot to remove the malloc call... Thanks for the answer!